# Diophantine equations and P=NP

Tags: complexity-theory, computability

It was proven that the problem of determining whether a given Diophantine equation has a solution is undecidable (and therefore has no polynomial time algorithm). But we can check proof certificates (that is, solutions to the equation) in linear time by plugging in our solution and evaluating. So the problem is in NP. Why does this not imply P $\neq$ NP?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every problem in **NP** is decidable. Since determining whether Diophantine equations have solutions is undecidable, it cannot be in **NP**.  Therefore, although the solution to the equation is a certificate, the size of this certificate is not bounded by any polynomial in the size of the input.

Comment: The certificate is precisely the size of the input; for example for the equation x^2 + y^2 = 2 one certificate would be (1,1) which is the same as the length of the left side of the equals: the certificate is the sane length as the number of variables.

Comment: One instance having a short certificate doesn't mean they all do (also, $1^2 + 2^2\neq 2$ but that's beside the point).

Comment: The size of a certificate isn't just the number of numbers in it, the size of the numbers themselves also contributes towards the size of the certificate.

Comment: Ya sorry that was a mistake but can you explain in more detail why the certificate is unbounded?

Comment: The size of the certificate is, as @TomvanderZanden says, the number of bits required to write out the answer. If that were bounded by a polynomial, the problem would be in NP but we know it's not in NP (because it's undecidable) so there can't be a polynomial bound. I don't, off the top of my head, know any examples of short Diophantine equations with large solutions and I'm not familiar with the undecidability proof so I can't give an answer that gives a more intuitive explanation than "Because it's undecidable."

Comment: @DavidRicherby I figured it out. Since the length of the numbers in the solution can be arbitrarily big and we have to do operations on those unbounded numbers the time to check is unbounded.

Comment: @RenéG No. The time to check is definitely polynomial in the number of bits required to write out the solution. But the number of bits required to write out the solution might be huge compared to the number of bits needed to write out the original equation.